# Match - fastlane is not automatically downloading the update provisioning profile (I added new devices in developer account)

Tags: ios, build, fastlane, fastlane-match

Match - Fastlane is not automatically downloading the updated provisioning profile (New Devices gets added).

I use this command

`match(type: "development", readonly: true, force_for_new_devices: true)`

if i do this:

`match(type: "development", force_for_new_devices: true)`

it creates
 every time new provisioning profile and that is annoying and flood the Apple account without deleting old ones.

Any help if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

match tool fixed this issue,

if I give a command :

`match(type: "development", force_for_new_devices: true)`

It fixes and update the old provisioning profile automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Just adding that you can also use `fastlane match development --force_for_new_devices` if you want to run it just one time. Also note that this is for the development provisioning profile, if you need to update your ad-hoc profile use `fastlane match adhoc --force_for_new_devices`. All info coming from here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#registering-new-devices